# Complex data.table subset and manipulation

Tags: r, loops, row, data.table, subset

I am trying to combine a lot of data.table manipulations into a some faster code.  I am creating an example with a smaller data.table and I hopeful someone has a better solution than the clunky (embarrassing) code I developed.

For each group, I want to:

1) Verify there is both a TRUE and FALSE in column w, and if there is:

2) Subtract the value of x corresponding to the highest value of v from each
value of x in the same group and put that that number in a new column

So in group 3, if the highest v value is 10, and in the same row x is 0.212,
I would subtract 0.212 from every x value corresponding to group 3 and put that number in a new column

3) Remove all rows corresponding to groups without both a TRUE and a FALSE in column w.

```
set.seed(1)
test <- data.table(v=1:12, w=runif(12)<0.5, x=runif(12),
y=sample(2,12,replace=TRUE), z=sample(letters[1:3],12,replace=TRUE) )
setkey(test,y,z)
test[,group:=.GRP,by=key(test)]
```

Comment: What is the "embarrassing" attempt you tried?

Answer (score 4):

A chained version can look like this without needing to set a table key:

```
result <- test[
  # First, identify groups to remove and store in 'rowselect'
  , rowselect := (0 < sum(w) & sum(w) < .N)
  , by = .(y,z)][
    # Select only the rows that we need
    rowselect == TRUE][
      # get rid of the temp column
      , rowselect := NULL][
        # create a new column 'u' to store the values
        , u := x - x[max(v) == v]
        , by = .(y,z)]
```

The result looks like this:

```
> result
    v     w         x y z         u
1:  1  TRUE 0.6870228 1 c 0.4748803
2:  3 FALSE 0.7698414 1 c 0.5576989
3:  7 FALSE 0.3800352 1 c 0.1678927
4: 10  TRUE 0.2121425 1 c 0.0000000
5:  8 FALSE 0.7774452 2 b 0.6518901
6: 12  TRUE 0.1255551 2 b 0.0000000
```

Comment: @jangorecki, thanks! Coding is about balancing performance and style :)